# calling a procedure to add two numbers with input output parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace procedure add(n1 in int,n2 in int,result out int)
as 
begin
result :=n1+n2;
end;
```

this procedure is created successfully,

```
declare result int;
begin
add(5,5,result);
dbms_output.putline(result);
end;
```

and this code is running successfully .
output:
    10

i have been given a task to get input parameters and add them and display the result without using `dbms_output.putline(result)` this command is there any possiblity to call a procedure and display result without using `dbms_output.putline(result)`
Need help

Comment: Do you mean... you need a function that returns a number instead?

Comment: You could 'display' the result in a file using UTL_FILE but not really sure what you are being asked to do.

Comment: In 12c you also have [implicit statement results](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#LNPLS118), but I don't think that's what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_TWO_INPUT (N1 IN NUMBER,N2 IN NUMBER,ADD_RESULT OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
ADD_RESULT := N1 + N2;
Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE(ADD_RESULT);
END;
/

DECLARE
RESULT NUMBER;
BEGIN
EXECUTE ADD_TWO_INPUT(1,2,:RESULT);
END;
/

result:-
3
```

Answer (score 1):

From the description it sounds like you want a function that returns a number, instead of a procedure that has an out parameter.

```
create or replace function add_numbers(n1 in int, n2 in int)
return int as
begin
  return n1+n2;
end;
/

select add_numbers(5, 5) from dual;

ADD_NUMBERS(5,5)
----------------
              10
```

I've changed the name because [`add` is a reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621)).

A function is a different thing to a procedure, but they are often referred to collectively as 'stored procedures', though Oracle class them as stored [PL/SQL subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS008). I'm assuming that your use of 'procedure' in your question is the more generic form that can include functions...

Not really relevant, but personally I tend to use `number` rather than `int`; at the moment this, or your code, will not allow floating-point numbers to be added properly:

```
select add_numbers(5.6, 5.6) from dual;

ADD_NUMBERS(5.6,5.6)
--------------------
                  11
```

With native number types instead:

```
create or replace function add_numbers(n1 in number, n2 in number)
return number as
begin
  return n1+n2;
end;
/

select add_numbers(5, 5) from dual;

ADD_NUMBERS(5,5)
----------------
              10

select add_numbers(5.6, 5.7) from dual;

ADD_NUMBERS(5.6,5.7)
--------------------
                11.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very different from what you are doing. I create a variable `c` in the surrounding environment (using SQL*Plus in this illustration); I populate it using your procedure, then I print it using the SQL*Plus `PRINT` command. I am not sure what this demonstrates, that wasn't there in your initial attempt.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure add_numbers(n1 in int,n2 in int,result out int)
  2  as
  3  begin
  4  result :=n1+n2;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable c number            -- SQL*Plus command to create c

SQL> exec add_numbers(2, 8, :c);  -- This assigns the OUT value to c

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print c

         C
----------
        10
```

Answer (score 0):

create or replace procedure add 3 input (a in a number,b in b number c add_out 3 input result) ) begin is a=a number; b=b number; c=a+b; declare dbms_output.put_line(add_3 input result); end \

Answer (score -1):

```
declare

-- declare variable x, y  
-- and z of datatype number 
x number(5);              
y number(5);             
z number(7);         

begin

-- Here we Assigning 10 into x 
x:=10;                  

-- Assigning 20 into x 
y:=20;                  

-- Assigning sum of x and y into z 
z:=x+y;                  

// Print the Result 
dbms_output.put_line('Sum is '||z);  
end;  
/                          
-- Program End
```